# How does an analyst decide what inequalities to prove?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, inequality

To my mind, the job of a modern analyst is rather misterious. Since the foundations of the central theory of modern analysis, much of the work I've been able to find involves proving certain inequalities regarding some sort of space. For example Central Morrey Spaces are a fertile ground for Harmonic Analysts but sometimes, inequalities can seem so complex and counterintuitive at first as to shy away from the original intention and sometimes (but not always) they serve to (bound an operator, study its behaviour somewhere...) .
My question is the following: How does an Analyst decide which space to study and what inequalities he should prove?

(I do not mean the fundamental inequalities like Cauchy-Schwarz, nor the ones which can precisey be worked backwards but rather  guess-type inequalities and bounds)

Comment: The general pathway to doing math: find a particular problem of interest, solve that particular problem, find what parts of the problems give it the interesting nature, generalize using those parts, solve the more general problem.

Comment: Please propose such a problem so that I can try to generalise some hidden sort inequality.

Comment: If I had such a problem that was easily solvable, I'd have solved it already.